# How to annotate a ggplot2 plot with latex2exp using variables?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is my sample code.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(latex2exp)
p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) + geom_point()
alpha=10
beta=20
p1 + annotate("label", x = 4, y = 25, label = TeX("$y = alpha e ^{betax}$"))
```

I was trying to get a label like `y=10e^{20x}`. Is it possible with [latex2exp](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/latex2exp/vignettes/using-latex2exp.html) or is there better way?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it with `latex2exp` would be to use `sprintf` to construct the LaTeX string:

```
p1 + annotate("label", x = 4, y = 25, label = TeX(sprintf("$y = %d e ^{%dx}$", alpha, beta)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `TeX(paste("$y = ", alpha, "e ^{", beta, " x}$"))`?

Comment: Works but I get a warning: `is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'expression'`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `bquote()` or `paste()` , and set the argument `parse=TRUE`

```r
library(ggplot2)
p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) + geom_point()
alpha=10
beta=20
p1 + 
  annotate("label", 
           x = 4, y = 25, 
           label = list(bquote(y==.(alpha)*e^{.(beta)*x})), parse= TRUE
  )
```

[image]

```r
p1 + 
  annotate("label", 
           x = 4, y = 25, 
           label = paste("y==", alpha, "*e^", "{", beta, "*x}"), parse= TRUE
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Hopes helpful for you.

Comment: A while ago I tried `label = bquote(y==.(alpha)*e^{.(beta)*x})`. The result is perfect _except_ that a redundant pair of brackets appears after the equation. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: @MatthewHui Sorry, I have no idea why. And it requires coerce your label to a list, such as `list(bquote(y==.(alpha)*e^{.(beta)*x}))`